# Why does this code not receive the complete output from an external command?

Tags: c#, cmd, processstartinfo

I am working on a tool to be able to find a PST on a specific drive. This code is taking the project path just because it's for testing purpose.

My problem is that when I try to get the output of the execution of a shell command in an external command processor, I only got the 2 first lines:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C dir /s *.pst";
p.Start();
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
MessageBox.Show(output);
p.WaitForExit();
```

My result:

> Volume in drive D is Data Volume Serial Number is 7C64-9650

Expected Result:

> Volume in drive D is Data Volume Serial Number is 7C64-9650
>
> Directory of D:\PATH   13/12/2012  01:49 PM     1,014,047,744
>   Archives.pst      4 File(s)  1,355,919,360 bytes

No error message are available.

Comment: I have tried on my PC. Works fine. I saw "Volume in drive D is Data Volume Serial Number is 7CXX-XXXX". But I used Console.WriteLine(output) instead of MessageBox.Show(output)

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing the `string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();` after the `p.WaitForExit();`?

Comment: @nick_w - no, that risks a deadlock. It's discussed in the docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps [another way to skin the cat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ta62wh3.aspx) would be easier? Your current code is not worth the trouble.

```
// .Net 2.0
string[] psts = Directory.GetFiles(".", "*.pst", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

// .Net 4.0+
var psts = Directory.EnumerateFiles(".", "*.pst", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Used like so:

```
MessageBox.Show(String.Join(", ", psts));
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your prompt answer. I tried and it works perfectly.. Thanks à lot!

Comment: @user1902146: No problem! The .Net Framework is *huge* and thus if you feel like you have to *run another program* to accomplish a goal, you probably don't. The trick is finding the functionality in MSDN :)